# Save textbox as variable without submitting

Tags: php, html

First I have this.

```
<form method="post" action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="varenummer" id="varenummer" onkeyup="gethint(this.value)" hidden=true style="display:none">
</form>
```

And then later on I have this

```
if (isset($_POST['tryk'])) {
$pri = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pri']);
$sek = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sek']);
$dat1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dat1']);
$dat2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dat2']);
$dat3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dat3']);
$dato = $dat1 . "-" . $dat2 . "-" . $dat3;
$tek = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tek']);
$id1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id1']);
$varenummer = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['varenummer']);

$insert = mysql_query("insert into Servicetxt (ID2, Servicenum, PriServiceTxt,
SekServiceTxt, Teknikker, Dato, Varenum) VALUES ('NULL', '$id1', '$pri', '$sek', '$tek',
'$dato', '$varenummer')")or die(mysql_error());    
}
```

The thing is, the submit-button 'tryk' is placed on an ajax page. How can I save the value of the textbox(varenummer) as a php-variable before the isset($_POST['tryk']), without pushing any button?

Comment: what are the main reason for doing this.? what is the code for gethint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is the sever-side programming language while JavaScript (jQuery) runs on the client-side.

we can use PHP to write JS, but JS can't affect PHP (except via AJAX or similar).

What you can do is use `SESSION`

here is sample code.

**Js Code**

```
$("#varenummer").change(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var data_posts = $(this).val();

    // Send Ajax request to backend.php
    $.post("/backend.php", {"varenummer": data_posts});
});
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
    // do any authentication first, then add POST variable to session
    $_SESSION['varenummer'] = $_POST['varenummer'];
?>
```

And the you can use that session variable globally as `$_SESSION` is **SUPER-GLOBAL** itself.